# Is it possible to show a form with fields for the jsonb properties

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, postgresql, jsonb

I have a Product model with a `jsonb` field called `dynamic`.

I have actually 2 product records

**Product 1 :**

```
dynamic = {"name": "super product 1", "description": "lorem ipsum text" }
```

**Product 2 :**

```
dynamic = {"title": "this is an ebook", "author": "john doe", "creation_date": "2015"}
```

To edit each product I need to show a form. for the **product 1** the form will contains 2 fields (name and description), and for **product 2** the form will contains 3 fields (title, author,creation_date)

I have searched but it seem that all the articles I have found talk about how to use the console to save or edit a json field but no one talks about how to use the form.

any help please ? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using simple_form you can do something like this:

```
f.simple_fields_for :dynamic do |dynamic_f|
  @product.dynamic.each do |k,v|
    dynamic_f.input k.to_sym
  end
end
```

Don't forget to allow the parameters in the controller like this:

```
params.require(:product).permit(dynamic: [:name, :description, :title, :author, :creation_date]])
```

It is always good practice to whitelist the specific params that you need but if you want to allow everything inside dynamic you can try something like this:

```
params.require(:product)permit( **permitted paramters in here** ).tap do |whitelisted|
  whitelisted[:dynamic] = params[:product][:dynamic] if params[:product][:dynamic]
end
```

Or to allow everything for the product model use:

```
params.require(:product).permit!
```

This is not recommended though as it would leave your other data outside of the json field open to be overwritten.

Comment: should I do something to allow these keys within strong parameters or in the model using attr_accessor or something like that ?

Comment: I do it with the strong parameters. I updated the answer to show how I handle it usually.

Comment: Thank you for the update, but keys of "dynamic" field are not fix, I create different keys each time , they can be other things not only (name, description, title, autohor, creation_date)

Comment: wow thank you so much for the update. can you just explain me what the code with "tap" method does ?

Comment: The tap is a helper to "tap" into a method chain which yields the object inside the block and then returns the object at the end. Basically what it does is extend the permitted parameters to allow all parameters passed by :dynamic to the controller. You can find some interesting discussion on this approach for strong parameters here: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/9454

Answer (score 0):

Hey @IngoAlbers I am using your approach in my forms and is working great, I just have a couple of inquiries that may add some features. Having this form:

```
<%= simple_form_for @user: :update do |form| %>
  <%= form.input :phone %>
  <%= form.simple_fields_for :group do |field| %>
    <%= field.input :name %>
  <% end %>
  <%= form.submit, "Update" %>
<% end %>
```

How can I let the input show an error on that specific field when validating?. I mean it is making the validation and not letting the method to continue but is not showing it in the field when rendering the page. The code and results:

```
errors.add :phone, :blank if phone.blank?
errors.add "group.name", :blank if group["name"].blank?
```

I've tried with `:"group.name"`, `:group_name` and some other similar stuff without success, the other association and attributes fields like `:phone` work just fine.

---

```
#<ActiveModel::Error attribute=phone, type=blank, options={}>,
#<ActiveModel::Error attribute=group_name, type=blank, options={}>,
```

And just for fun, it would be great if there's a way to use translations as labels in fields_for. For example:

```
es:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      user:
        phone: Teléfono móvil
        group:
          name: Grupo
```

I have also tried with `group.name`, `group_name` and nothing, here is the result of everything:

[image]

I know there's a way to do it, hope you can help me.